# php cookies error

Tags: php, cookies

```
<form action=userLogin.php method=post>
    <div id="login">
        <div id="submit" class="h">Log In</div>
        &nbsp;Email
        <br>
        &nbsp;<input id="email" name="email" type="email" required>
        <br>
        &nbsp;Password
        <br>
        &nbsp;<input name="pass" type="password" required=required><br>
        &nbsp;<a href="recover.php">Forgot your password</a><br>

        <div id="submit">
            <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Remember&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div id="h">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
if (empty($_POST['pass']) == false) {
    $uname = $_POST['email'];

    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    include("config.php");
    $query   = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$uname' AND password='$pass'");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        if ($numrows == 0) {
            ?>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#alert").fadeIn();
                });</script>
        <?php
        }
        else {
            $id = $row[id];
            setcookie('userId', $id);


        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is my code which get user data and check whether the user exists or not and set cookie on the user's browser. 
When i check that the cookie is set I could see only phpMyAdmin cookies not my userId cookie.You can see the screenshot[image] and the browser got stucked and its automatically closed
But when i editted setcookie function with `setcookie('userId','$id');` the cookie was set but its value is `%24id`[$id]. So how can i set the cookie in the value of the variable $row[id] is the error with my pc or server or with my code?
When i used chrome with $id without qoutes the error came `This webpage is not available The webpage at localhost/mysite/mysite/userLogin.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address`

Comment: `setcookie('userId', $id)` will work. You don't need quotes around `$id`. (As long as `$id` is not empty, of course.)

Comment: but other ways chrome is showing This webpage is not available
The webpage at http://localhost/mysite/mysite/userLogin.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: @DCoder: He's actually using `mysqli`, but your code is still vulnerable to SQL injection! Read about prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cookies have to be sent with headers.

"setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php